# .NET Core C# MVC DBContext is Null in class file

Tags: c#, static, null, dbcontext

I have a solution that has several 'projects' inside. One being a MVC Web App and the other being a class library.

In my MVC Web App Startup.cs I am registering the DbContext:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
     services.AddSession();
     services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
     services.AddMemoryCache();
     services.AddSingleton<Controllers.HomeController>();
     services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

     services.AddDbContext<AffiliateDatabaseContext>();
}
```

I have the Context in the class library all setup with the on configuring being setup to the connection string within the appsettings (works):

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
     if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
     {
          IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
          optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("CustomerBilling"));
     }
}
```

I am trying to use the DBContext within a class file in my class library doing a DI:

```cs
private static AffiliateDatabaseContext affilContext;

public PromotionLogic(AffiliateDatabaseContext _affilContext)
{
      affilContext = _affilContext;
}
public static IEnumerable<AffPromotion> GetAllPromotions()
{
      return affilContext.AffPromotion.Include("Company").Include("PromotionType").Include("Audience").Include("PromotionSportLink").Include("AffPromotionImage").OrderBy(x => x.Priority).AsEnumerable();
}
```

However it seems `affilContext` is NULL and I keep getting the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

Am I doing this wrong? Do I need an interface or something instead? It seems to work fine within a controller.

Would another way be just passing the DBContext through as an arguement to the function?

Comment: It is very odd to use `_` at the start of parameter names. It makes the code quite hard to read.

Comment: `PromotionLogic` must be created by asp.net IOC container, then container will be able to inject your `AffiliateDatabaseContext` dependency (i.e. you can inject PromotionLogic into controller). It also bad practice  to have `HomeController` as singleton. It will cause problems for parallel requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are assigning to a `static` field in an `instance` constructor. Since you never invoke the constructor, the field remains `null`. The solution is to use an instance field (no `static`).

Thus:

```
private static AffiliateDatabaseContext affilContext;
```

must be:

```
private AffiliateDatabaseContext affilContext;
```

*Once you make this change, any `static` method using `affilContext` will need to be changed to be non-static (i.e. remove `static`) as well.*

You may be tempted to leave the variable as `static`. This is not a good idea, generally speaking, with regards to DB contexts. They are not designed to be long lived, and they aren't thread-safe. Thus `static` DB contexts are not appropriate for use in a web app.

Comment: I have removed static from the functions. But I am just getting 'An object reference is required for the none-static field, method, or propety'. I have updated my question at the bottom.

Comment: You need to `new` up (or inject) an instance of `PromotionLogic` and call methods on the instance (rather than against `PromotionLogic` directly). Ultimately, that is a new question though.